# Why I am getting different output for string pool while comparing two objects in java?

Tags: java, string, string-pool

I am running this program. To check string pool concept. I refer [this link](https://www.journaldev.com/797/what-is-java-string-pool)  and added two more lines with equals method from Object class in java. Why I am getting different output for objRef1==objRef2 vs objRef1.equals(objeRef2). In my opinion they should be same.

```
public class Abc2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "Cat";
        String s2 = "Cat";
        String s3 = new String("Cat");

        System.out.println("s1 == s2 :"+(s1==s2));
        System.out.println("s1.equals(s2) :"+(s1.equals(s2)));
        System.out.println("s1 == s3 :"+(s3==s2));
        System.out.println("s1.equals(s3) :"+(s3.equals(s2)));
    }
}
```

Comment: `==` denotes reference equality (are they same point in memory); `equals` denotes "content equality" are the contents of the two objects the same (ie are the two objects the same type and does `Cat` equal `Cat` and not `Dog`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer that means equals method from Object class is overridden in String class.

Comment: Yes, you could inspect the source code to see

Comment: krishna, I think you are correct in detail - but generally @MadProgrammer is right: the semantics of equals() are "content equality" while those of == are "reference equality".  Object.equals() itself may be implemented as "reference equality" because there was nothing else it could do...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, you are correct. I am so impatient.

Comment: Are you saying that `s1 == s2` gives a different result than `s1.equals(s2)`?

Comment: @Henry: Yes, it can, and often does. If they were always the same, there would be no point having both. (Not in this specific case, since `s1` and `s2` are the same object, but in case of `s2` and `s3`, they are different.)

Comment: @Amadan `s1`and `s2` are set to the same constant string from the string pool. So they should always be the same object, right?

Comment: Yes. I did not know whether you were referring specifically to this `s1` and `s2`, or any `s1` and `s2`. These specific `s1` and `s2` are both `==` and `equals`, as the OP's code demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

String is a complex datatype so == find two different refetences.
Strings equals() compares the content instead of the reference.
So two "Cat"s has the same content but arent the same object.
Its like you try to say C:\test.txt and C:\test2.txt where the same file because they have the same content.